# Implement standard english calendar plugin in tamil wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins

I refered [this Link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-plugin-admin-pages-language-without-modifying-default-wp-config)

I need to implement a english calendar plugin in tamil wordpress.That plugin must want to go for a particular post if i click on the date of the post.

[image]

Here i want to change the month in other language.